# jQuery selector - Remove elements if parent div is not of specific ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Assume the following markup:

```
<div id="NotificationBar">Stuff</div>
<div id="StatusBar>
    <p>Stuff</p>
</div>

<div id="myContainer>
    <div id="NotificationBar">Stuff</div>
    <div id="StatusBar>
        <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
<div>
```

What I want is the following:

- If `#NotificationBar` and `#StatusBar` are **not** within the `#myContainer` - remove them from DOM

The final markup I want thus is:

```
<div id="myContainer>
    <div id="NotificicationBar">Stuff</div>
    <div id="StatusBar>
        <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
<div>
```

I tried the following, but end up removing the whole parent which is not what I want:

```
$("#StatusBar").parent('div').not('#myContainer').remove()
$("#NotificationBar").parent('div').not('#myContainer').remove()
```

I can't just hide stuff via CSS, I really need to remove the elements from the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID of an element must be ***unique***, so use class to group similar elements

```
<div class="NotificationBar">Stuff</div>
<div class="StatusBar">
    <p>Stuff</p>
</div>
<div id="myContainer">
    <div class="NotificationBar">Stuff</div>
    <div class="StatusBar">
        <p>Stuff</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then

```
$('.NotificationBar, .StatusBar').not('#myContainer .NotificationBar, #myContainer .StatusBar').remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dv4Cz/)

Comment: Even though classes would be correct in this case - multiple IDs we have... :)